# How to connect to a Database using SSH tunnel on dbeaver?

Tags: postgresql, ssh, dbeaver

I would like to understand why I can't connect to my database using the ssh tunnel on dbeaver.

My database is hosted on a VPS using nginx.

I installed postgresql and created a user "userA" with a password "passwordUserA".
I created a new database "databaseA".
and gave the rights to the previously created user "userA

```
CREATE USER userA WITH PASSWORD 'passwordUserA' CREATEDB;
CREATE DATABASE databaseA;
ALTER DATABASE databaseA OWNER TO userA;
```

Now I would like to be able to connect to it remotely with dbeaver.

for the host ip: I enter the @ ip of my remote server

the username: userA

the password: passwordUserA

the port: 22

dBeaver ssh connection settings
[image: dbeaver ssh connection settings]

I should be able to connect to my database but dbeaver says "auth fail"
Does anyone know why the connection is not working properly?

Comment: "auth fail" does not sound like a real error message.  At least for me, both DBeaver and PostgreSQL produce far more detailed, or at least more verbose, error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SSH connection you should to use linux system user with password (or ssh key) not database user.

After SSH connection established you put Database user and password on the 'Main' tab, using localhost as Host
[image]